# Name of a degenerate foliation

Tags: differential-geometry

Last summer I went to a talk where the speaker had a specific name for a certain kind of degenerated foliation on a manifold. Sadly, I forgot that name.

**Question :** what is that name ?

(Sorry if my question is vague)

e.g. If you look at the level sets of $f(x,y)= x^2-y^2$ on $\mathbb R^2$ you get that sort of degenerated foliation.

Comment: Do you remember the name of the speaker?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I should simply write directly to him.

Comment: So I thought I knew the speaker's name and wrote to him. Bad luck. It wasn't him. Then I thought it was this other guy. I wrote to him. Wasn't him either... this question is still open.

Comment: Mind if I ask who the speaker and the other guy were? I have a bit of background in foliations.